# Replacing a character string in R

Tags: r

I am trying to remove/replace a certain part in the character strings.

Data:

```
b <- "Brunswick North Brunswick (Vic.) Bellfiled (Banyule - Vic.)"
```

I would like the result to look like:

```
"Brunswick North Brunswick Bellfield"
```

I have tried doing:

```
sub("(Vic.)", "", b, fixed = TRUE)
```

By doing so, I get the required output for the second element i.e. "Brunswick" but not for the third element.

Comment: Apologies, will do, feedback taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `gsub`

```
gsub("\\([^)]*Vic\\.\\)", "", b)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace everything that is inside the parantheses then try this. This will remove the brackets and everything inside it.

```
gsub("\\s*\\([^\\)]+\\)","",b)
```

Comment: -thanks, I am very new to programming, could you possibly explain what the first part of the function doing using all those "strokes" and "braces" etc trying to do?

Comment: This should explain it: [link](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=\\s*\\%28[^\\%29]%2B\\))